# Prove: If this system is solvable, then this dual system is not.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to get a handle on algebraic dual spaces, and it's hurting my head.

To be proven:

Let $A$ be a $m \times n$-matrix and $b$ be a $1 \times n$-matrix. Show that the system $$\begin{cases} Ax = 0 \\ bx \not = 0 \end{cases}$$ is solvable if and only if the dual system $$A^ty = b^t$$ has no solution.

What's striking to me is that since I can consider $b$ as a linear functional, then $b^t \in A^t$,  and then the second system will be solvable? Something has gone horribly wrong? Maybe I'm confused by notation and since $b$ is a linear functional, and then $b \in A^t$ and $b^t \in (A^t)^t = A$? But then again, if I make $b$ a basis vector, which is a row vector, then the correspoding vector in the dual space (in this case) will be $b^t$?

I was thinking about the kernel of A, and kernel of the dual space, I mean of course both should will have a kernel, since $Ax = 0$, but $x \not = 0$, but that doesn't help me...

What would be a good way to start?
I don't think this should be too hard, a nudge in the right direction would be nice though.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No one has anything at all to say about this? :/

Answer (score 1):

Let me denote $b$ as $u^t$ where $u$ is a $n\times 1$ matrix.

- If there exist $y$ such that $A^t y=b^t=u$ then $y^tA=u^t$ then if $Ax=0$ we certainly have $u^t x=y^t Ax=0$ then there is no solution for $Ax=0$ and $u^t x\ne 0$. So it's true that if there is a solution, $A^t y=b^t$ must have no solution.
- Inversely, assuming that $A^t y=b^t=u$ or $y^tA=u^t$ has no solution. It's obvious that $u\ne 0$. Therefore $A^t$ is not surjective, therefore $\exists Im(A^t)^\bot\ne\varnothing$. Because $u\notin Im(A^t)$ so $u\notin (Im(A^t)^\bot)^\bot$ so $\exists x\in Im(A^t)^\bot$ such that $u^t x\ne 0$, then $x$ is a solution of $Ax=0$ and $u^t x\ne 0$. ($x\in Im(A^t)^\bot$ so $x^tA^ty=0$   $\forall y$ or $y^tAx=0$   $\forall y$ or $Ax=0$)